# fail2ban ipv6 support doesn't work

Tags: linux, wordpress, ipv6, iptables, fail2ban

I've installed fail2ban in my web hosting and it is monitoring wordpress login attemps through the access_log file. Once I configured fail2ban to filter wp logins with this regexp:

```
failregex = ^<HOST> .* "POST /wp-login.php
```

... the attack was changed through a ipv6 host. I read fail2ban doc and I noticed that there is not ipv6 support in fail2ban (yet). Then, I applied this workaround:
[fail2ban ipv6 support](https://tetsumaki.net/blog/article/2014-03-04-ajout-du-support-ipv6-sur-fail2ban.html)(in french)

As you can see in this tutorial, I created 2 new actions called iptables46* and I defined them in the jail.local in order to be executed when fail2ban detects the new regexp for ipv4 and ipv6 (changed in the patched python scripts).

I've checked fail2ban logs and it seems that it is detecting the ipv6 calls, but a warning is displayed before each filter detection:

```
2016-10-26 23:00:55,539 fail2ban.filter         [24963]: WARNING Unable to find a corresponding IP address for 127.0.0.1/8: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
2016-10-26 23:00:55,540 fail2ban.filter         [24963]: INFO    [wp-auth] Found xxxx:xxxx:xxx::xxxx:xxx
```

(xxxx:xxxx:xxx::xxxx:xxx is the attacker host ipv6)

I've checked fail2ban status with : `fail2ban-regex access_log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/wp-auth.conf` and there are a lot of results   (regexp and the filter are ok), but the host is not blocked by iptables. I've checked ip6tables with  :

```
ip6tables -S | grep f2b
```

and the results:

```
-A f2b-default -s 2002:5bc8:c41::5bc8:c41/128 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
```

also if I check the status of the fail2ban filter: fail2ban-client status wp-auth
:

```
Status for the jail: wp-auth
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 1
|  |- Total failed:     93
|  `- File list:        /opt/wordpress/logs/access_log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 1
   |- Total banned:     2
   `- Banned IP list:   xxxx:xxxx:xxx::xxxx:xxx
```

It seems that the ipv6 is not blocked because the host is still launching requests.

I don't know why fail2ban log is displaying a WARNING (related to a 127.0.0.1/8: [Errno -2]), if the created ip6table rule is ok... I don't know why the host is not been blocked.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Good news are that **fail2ban** released support for IPv6 recently.

For Debian IPv6 servers I would recommend to follow [this tutorial](http://ncomputers.org/fail2ban).

For CentOS IPv6 servers, I would recommend to download it [here](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban) and then execute these commands replacing the version number accordingly:

```
tar xvfj fail2ban-0.11.0.tar.bz2
cd fail2ban-0.11.0
python setup.py install
```

Make sure a jail for sshd is enabled in **/etc/fail2ban/jail.local**, for example:

```
[sshd]
enabled=1
```